# Error with - (void) reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Hi I am using this tutorial from [**HERE**](https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) to create a SQLite Database and view it on a Table View. Right now I am facing a error on my app and I have no clue on debugging it. If anyone can help me out on this error please do!

Thank you very much!!!

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

**Here are my codes for my current ViewController.m**
I have tried running zombie mode but it doesn't help with debugging the error that I am currently facing...

```
import "ViewController.h"

import "DBManager.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrPeopleInfo;

-(void)loadData;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Make self the delegate and datasource of the table view.
    self.tblPeople.delegate = self;
    self.tblPeople.dataSource = self;
}

-(void)editingInfoWasFinished{
    // Reload the data.
    [self loadData];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    EditInfoViewController *editInfoViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    editInfoViewController.delegate = self;
}

-(void)loadData{
    // Form the query.
    NSString *query = @"select * from peopleInfo";

    // Get the results.
    if (self.arrPeopleInfo != nil) {
        self.arrPeopleInfo = nil;
    }
    self.arrPeopleInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

    // Reload the table view.
    [self.tblPeople reloadData];

    // Load the data.
    [self loadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.arrPeopleInfo.count;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 60.0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Dequeue the cell.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCellRecord" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger indexOfFirstname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"firstname"];
    NSInteger indexOfLastname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"lastname"];
    NSInteger indexOfAge = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"age"];

    // Set the loaded data to the appropriate cell labels.
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfFirstname], [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfLastname]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Age: %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfAge]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)addNewRecord:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idSegueEditInfo" sender:self];
}
@end
```

Comment: it would be much better if you post your code

Comment: @GIJOW Hi I have added in my code for my ViewController.m would you kindly assist me thanks!

Comment: You're calling `loadData` recursively at the end of `loadData`. You can see on the left that the function is calling itself over and over. Also, in general, it's best to strip your example code down to the bare minimum that will still reproduce the problem. That makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you recursively call the same method

```
-(void)loadData{

   // Reload the table view.
     [self.tblPeople reloadData];

   // Load the data.
    [self loadData]; // should comment this
}
```